# asking if user wants to use Location Services

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, location

How does the process of "asking if user wants to use Location Services" work?

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369939/application-crashes-when-asking-if-user-wants-to-use-location-services) that a dialog at the installation appears, which asks the user if Location Services should be allowed or not. Does it mean that there is nothing to do for the developer, because the user can change this behavior in settings? So there is no "asking dialog" to implement and no storing in system settings? Does the app need a settings menu where this behavior can be changed?

What is if I want such a settings menu in my app?

The only thing the developer has to be aware of is to check in his code if it is allowed or not? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439947/how-do-you-determine-with-cllocationmanager-when-a-user-denies-access-to-location).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds reasonable isn't it ?  Yes, that's it. No dialog to implement yourself, iOS manages that for you.

The user can change the settings in Settings/General/Location Service.

Comment: What do you think about the app store guideline 4.1: `Apps that do not notify and obtain user consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data will be rejected.` Do I have to do something more? I thought the iOS does this!?

Comment: I mentioned that either.  Probably to prevent anyone to try dismissing the dialog programmatically..  I don't know really.

Comment: I also think so. But didn't know if this is possible.